# How can I set the default email adress for the from field in Gmail Composer

Tags: android, gmail

While starting the Gmail Composer **com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivity** in my App,  I can use the intent parameter EXTRA_EMAIL set the to email adress. Is there anyway that can set the default from email address for ComposeActivity if I have more than one Gmail account on my device?

```
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.setType("plain/text");
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, cc@gmail.com);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_BCC, "bcc@gmail.com");
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, "cc@gmail.com");
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.?????, "from@gmail.com"); //Can we set the from email?
    sendIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.gm");
    startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

try this

emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, aEmailList);

and aEmailList is
String aEmailList[] = { "user@host.com","user2@host.com" };

Hope this will help you.