# Send mail by using android-Intent fails

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to create an E-Mail by using intent. I've got the following Code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
intent.setType("message/rfc822");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
        "bla@test.com");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "I'm email body.");

startActivity(intent);
```

After this the mail client open and Subject and text are filled, but Email adress is still empty. Have anyone an idea why it fails?

Comment: [http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/03/send-email-using-intentactionsend.html](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/03/send-email-using-intentactionsend.html)

Comment: Check this out:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216322/how-can-i-set-the-default-email-adress-for-the-from-field-in-gmail-composer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"youremail@yahoo.com"});          
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "message");
email.setType("message/rfc822");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));
```

[Look This](http://www.mkyong.com/android/how-to-send-email-in-android/)